# Are exceptions well handeled in this code? Is it missing a finally block to close the fileobject?

Tags: java, ioexception

```
void appendFile() throws IOException{
    
    
    FileWriter print = new FileWriter(f, true);
    
    
    String info = GetData.getWord("Write desired info to File");
    print.append(" "); //Write Data
    print.append(info);
    
    System.out.println("this executes");
    print.flush();
    print.close();
      
}
boolean fileExist(){
    return f.exists();
    
}
try{
        if (f.fileExist())
            f.appendFile();
        else {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm not sure if the ecxeption is well handeled? The FileWriter is not going to be created if there is a fileNotFoundException, therefore don't need to be closed. However, is it possible that this code throws another kind of IOException after the file was opened?, and in that case do I need a finally block to close the file.

Comment: Rule of thumb is, code that opens something should close it. If you didn’t open it, don’t close it. Use your IDE to tell what is thrown where, or read the API doc.

Comment: Not sure if it will be useful for your specific case, but usually if you feel the need to `close` in a `finally`, a lot of the time you can use [try-with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).  I would look into it if you haven't already.

Comment: Given that `File` (assumed to be the type of `f`) doesn't have a `close()` method, you can't close it. But the `FileWriter` you're opening should be closed even in the case of an exception, i.e. you should either use a "try-with-resources" (`try(FileWriter print = new FileWriter(f, true)) { ...}` or a plain old try-finally (`FileWriter print = new FileWriter(f, true); try { ... } finally { print.close()}`).

Comment: Side note: a try-block doesn't have to catch any exception (i.e. a try-with.resources) - or it can catch and re-throw them.

Comment: If you look at the docs for file writer, there are two other examples of an IOException caused even when the file exists. "if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason"

Comment: @matt printing an exception is a way of handling it. It could be done better but it's 1000 times better than the empty catch blocks you can see in some code that's posted here.

Comment: You should add some kind of message to your IOException. Something like `throw new IOException("File doesn't exist");`

Comment: @Nexevis looking into it, thanks!

Comment: @matt yes and that's totally fine if it fits the design. You might want to force the calling code to deal with the exception so you throw it but at the same time want to make sure any closables opened internally are properly closed. So you could use a try-with-resources to handle the auto-closing and have the exception bubble up. (And there are other similar situations where a "normal" try-finally might be used the same way, or even some exceptions being caught while others aren't and are added to the throws clause instead).

Answer (score 1):

No.

### It doesn't safely close the resource

The general rule is, if you call a constructor of an object that represents a closable resource, *or* a method that returns one which documents that this counts as 'opening the resource', which often but not always includes `new` being part of the method name (examples: `socket.getInputStream()`, `Files.newInputStream`), then you are responsible for closing it.

The problem is, what if an exception occurs? So, you have to use try/finally, except that's a mouthful, so there's a convenient syntax for this.

The appendFile method should use it; it isn't, that makes it bad code. This is correct:

```
try (FileWriter print = new FileWriter(f, true)) {
    String info = GetData.getWord("Write desired info to File");
    print.append(" "); //Write Data
    print.append(info);
    System.out.println("this executes");
}
```

Not how it is not neccessary to flush before close (`close` implies `flush`), and in this case, not neccessary to `close()` - the try construct does it for you. It *also* does it for you if you get out of the `{}` of the `try` via a `return` statement, via control flow (`break`), or via an exception, or just by running to the `}` and exiting normally. No matter how - the resource is closed. As it should be.

### It throws description-less exceptions

`else throw new IOException();` is no good; add a description that explains *why* the exception happened. `throw new IOException("File not found")` is better, but `throw new FileNotFoundException(f.toString())` is even better: The message should convey useful information and nothing more than that (in other words, `throw new IOException("Something went wrong")` is horrible, don't do that, that message adds no useful information), should not end in punctuation (`throw new IOException("File not found!")` is bad), and should throw a type that is most appropriate (if the file isn't there, `FileNotFoundException`, which is a subtype of `IOException`, is more appropriate, obviously).

### It commits the **capital offense**

You should not ever write a catch block whose contents are just `e.printStackTrace();`. **This is always wrong**.

Here's what you do with a checked exception:

1. First, think of what the exception means and whether the nature of your method inherently implies that this exception can occur (vs. that it is an implementation detail). In this case, you didn't show us what the method containing that try/catch stuff even does. But let's say it is called `appendFile`, **obviously** a method that includes the text 'file' does I/O, and therefore, that method **should** be declared with `throws IOException`. It's not an implementation detail that a method named `appendFile` interacts with files. It is its nature.

This is somewhat in the eye of the beholder. Imagine a method named `saveGame`. That's less clear; perhaps the mechanism to save may involve a database instead, in which case `SQLException` would be normal. That's an example of a method where 'it interacts with the file system' is an implementation detail.

2. The problem that the exception signals is logical, but needs to be more abstract.

See the above: A save file system can obviously fail to save, but the exact nature of the error is abstract: If the save file system is DB-based, errors would show up in the form of an `SQLException`; if a file system, `IOException`, etcetera. However, the idea that saving may fail, and that the code that tried to save has a reasonable chance that it can somewhat recover from this, is obvious. If it's a game, there's a user interface; you should most absolutely TELL the player that saving failed, instead of shunting some stack trace into sysout which they probably never even look at! Telling the user that something failed is one way of handling things, not always the best, but here it applies).

In such cases, **make your own exception type** and throw that, using the wrapper constructor:

```
public class SaveException extends Exception {
  public SaveException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
  }
}

// and to use:

public void save() throws SaveException {
  try {
    try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(savePath)) {
      game.saveTo(out);
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new SaveException(e);
  }
}
```

3. If neither applies, then perhaps the exception is either essentially not handleable or not expectable or nearly always a bug. For example, writing to an outputstream that you *know* is a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (which can't throw), trying to load the `UTF-8` charset (which is guaranteed by the JVM spec and therefore cannot possibly throw `NoSuchCharsetException`) - those are not expectable. Something like `Pattern.compile("Some-regexp-here")` can fail (not all strings are valid regexps), but as the vast majority of regexes in java are literals written by a programmer, any error in them is therefore neccessarily a bug. Those, too, are properly done as RuntimeExceptions (which are exceptions you don't have to catch or list in your `throws` line). Not handleables are mostly an application logic level thing. All fair game for runtimeexceptions. Make your own or use something that applies:

```
public void save(int saveSlot) {
  if (saveSlot < 1 || saveSlot > 9) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Choose a saveslot from 1 to 9");
  // ... rest of code.
}
```

This really feels like door number one: Whatever method this is in probably needs to be declared as `throws IOException` and do no catching or trying at all.

### Minor nit: Uses old API

There's new API for file stuff in the `java.nio.file` package. It's 'better', in that the old API does a bunch of bad things, such as returning failure by way of a `boolean` flag instead of doing it right (by throwing an exception), and the new API has far more support for various bits and bobs of what file systems do, such as support for file links and creation timestamps.